# Disabling the 'Copy' feature in iPad Safari browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, ipad, mobile-safari

In Safari for `iPad` in `iOS6`, I would like to select text and then highlight it (changing the background color) using JavaScript. However, when I do text selection a "Copy" option automatically pops up. How would I go about disabling this "Copy" option? I'm able to get this working on every other browser, except on `iPad` Safari.

Is this possible? What should I do?

Comment: I think that is what you need, please tell me if otherwise.

Comment: Trufa - I need to select the text and then change the background of the selected text (to yellow or something, i.e. highlight it). The problem in mobile Safari is that a "Copy" button pops once I select the text. I'm able to disable the "Copy" feature from functioning, i.e. actually not copy anything, but I'm not able to prevent that button from popping up up in the first place

Comment: I'm afraid that if the text is selectable, the the copy popup will popup, you can't alter that... I'll only say this as comment because I'm not sure.

Answer (score 22):

> If you want to disable the 'Cut / Copy / Paste' invoked by holding
>   down on an element in Safari on the iPhone or iPad use the css:

```
-webkit-user-select: none;
```

Info from the [Disabling ‘hold to copy’ on Mobile Safari](http://bencollier.net/2010/04/disabling-hold-to-copy-on-mobile-safari/), posted by Ben Collier

---

> the -webkit-tap-highlight-color property accepts any standard CSS
>   color value, but you’ll probably want to provide an rgba value in
>   order to control the alpha transparency. Disabling the tap highlight
>   is as simple as setting the alpha value to 0, like so:

```
container {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

Info from [Quick Tip: Customizing the Mobile Safari tap highlight color](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/10/01/quick-tip-customizing-the-mobile-safari-tap-highlight-color/) posted by Ryan Grove

---

So I would use css not javaScript.

Comment: This prevents text selection, but doesn't solve my problem, unfortunately.

Comment: look again, I suggest going with css

Comment: Let me try this. Thanks, Comradsky

Comment: Hey, were you successful, or do you still need help.

Comment: Thanks for checking, Comradsky. I couldn't get this to work the way I want. After highlighting I have to save it so that when the user come in next time they can see their old highlights (some way to indicate that highlighting was done on that selection). The one you suggested, from what I could see, only allows you to change the default color when you tap on the text. Let me know if I'm wrong. Thx again.

Answer (score 0):

Addition to accepted answer;

Giving the mentioned property to only a carrier div or to body element, holding on some objects (Images and SVG elements etc.) still brings up the tooltip.

```
* {
-webkit-user-select: none;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

Giving the properties to all elements (*) did the trick for me.

---

Also I'm guessing user-select has a problem/bug with text input, so you might want to exclude it.

```
input {
-webkit-user-select: auto;
}
```